# How to run Clickonce app from local cache

Tags: clickonce

I have 2 machines with .appref-ms links to the long-dead server (1 year+) with some valuable clickonce applications made by long-dead 3rd party. Somehow 1st machine launches it from the cache and the other one start checking for updates and breaks bcs ofc server no longer exists. How to skip updates check or/and build .application from the local cache?

As I see everything app needs stored in %User%/Appdata/Local/Apps/2.0/*obscuredname*/*obscuredname2* and there is both deployment manifest and application manifests in different folders. There is .exe file of needed application but it's version 1.0.0.0 while on 1st machine launches 2.1.1.3.
On both machines in local application manifest (stored is ./manifests) states update check max age = 0 days, I tried deleting  part completely + rebooting but it doesn't make it.